# Unable to debug cakephp error Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: cakephp

Here is my model

```
<?php
class Survey extends AppModel {

    // model associations
    public $belongsTo = array( 
    'Organisation' => array( 
      'className' => 'Organisation', 
      'foreignKey' => 'organisation_id' 
    ),
    'Account' => array( 
      'className' => 'Account', 
      'foreignKey' => 'account_id' 
    ),
    'User' => array( 
      'className' => 'User', 
      'foreignKey' => 'user_id' 
    ),
    'Country' => array( 
      'className' => 'Country', 
      'foreignKey' => 'country_id' 
    ),
    'Currency' => array( 
      'className' => 'Currency', 
      'foreignKey' => 'currency_id' 
    )
  );

}
?>
```

and here is my controller

```
<?php
class SurveysController extends AppController {
public $components = array('Session');
public $uses = array('Report', 'Mycase', 'Workflow');

public function add($type = null, $id = null) {

    if (!$id || !$type) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid link'));
        }

    $type = Inflector::camelize($type);

    // this populates the form select for country allowing the country from the report to be prepopulated
    $countries = $this->$type->Country->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('countries'));

    // this populates the form select for currency
    $currencies = $this->Survey->Currency->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('currencies'));

    $resources = $this->$type->find('first',
        array(
        'conditions' => array($type.'.id' => $id, $type.'.account_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.account_id')),
        'recursive' => -1 //int
        ));
    if (!$resources) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('You are not authorised to access that location'));
        }
    $this->set('resources', $resources);

}

}
```

The error lies in this line of code in the controller

```
$currencies = $this->Survey->Currency->find('list');
```

I have a database table with Currencies in it and I am trying to populate that to the Survey view in a select. I have checked that the model and controller are named correctly. My associations are similar to the country select that I am also using, which works properly, but I am getting this error on the Currency lookup and I have been trying to debug for hours.

```
Fatal Error
Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object 
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp2-5-3\app\Controller\SurveysController.php 
Line: 29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you where to look: **line 29** of **SurveysController.php**.

Chances are you’re calling `find()` on a model you’ve not included. If it’s `Survey`, then you need to add it to the `$uses` property in your controller so that it’s loaded.

Comment: But if I am in a function in the SurveysController then I don't need to add Survey to the $uses property right?

Comment: @RichardRoss No. As you’ve overridden the `$uses` array, you’ll need to explicitly declare `Survey` again (`public $uses = array('Report', 'Mycase', 'Workflow', 'Survey');`). CakePHP doesn’t know to merge it back in as it thinks you’re trying to override the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you Martin you fixed my problem. I love stackoverflow!

Comment: @RichardRoss Awesome! :)